# how to customize URL in Wordpress 4.8

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.8

I have a simple question. I do not know how to add custom url in my latest version of wordpress today. 
In the following snap.
[image: custom url to the menu]

The top menu is the one that i want to customize. Inspecting it and adding 
 a style of `display none`, i got the result. But I do not know how to add this Customize->custom-url. Do any one know how to ..
The following is the source code as follows:

```
<div class="full-container">
                    <a href="http://www.keynesdeepak.com/blog/" title="Deepak’s Website" rel="home" class="logo" style="
    /* display: none; */
"><img src="http://www.keynesdeepak.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/deepak_logo.png" class="logo-height-constrain" width="369" height="214" alt="Deepak's Website Logo"><h1 class="site-title logo-title" style="">Deepak's Website</h1></a>
                            <div id="search-icon">
                <div id="search-icon-icon"><div class="vantage-icon-search"></div></div>

<form method="get" class="searchform" action="http://www.keynesdeepak.com/blog/" role="search" style="width: 1080px;">
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search">
</form>
            </div>

                    <div id="so-mobilenav-standard-1" data-id="1" class="so-mobilenav-standard"></div><div class="menu" style="
"><ul>
<li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://www.keynesdeepak.com/blog/"><span class="icon"></span>Home</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-45"><a href="http://www.keynesdeepak.com/blog/blog/"><span class="icon"></span>Blog</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-41"><a href="http://www.keynesdeepak.com/blog/contact-me/"><span class="icon"></span>Contact Me</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-43"><a href="http://www.keynesdeepak.com/blog/gallery/"><span class="icon"></span>Gallery</a></li>
</ul></div>
<div id="so-mobilenav-mobile-1" data-id="1" class="so-mobilenav-mobile"></div><div class="menu-mobilenav-container"><ul id="mobile-nav-item-wrap-1" class="menu"><li><a href="#" class="mobilenav-main-link" data-id="1"><span class="mobile-nav-icon"></span>Menu</a></li></ul></div>          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Appearance -> Menus and add new custom link to your menu and drag it according to the order you want.

see the screenshot below:

[image: custom menu in wordpress]

Answer (score 0):

Edit your first url, go to theme appearance editor

```
<a href="http://www.keynesdeepak.com/blog/" title="Deepak’s Website" rel="home" class="logo" style="
```

Comment: do you mean Appearence->Theme settings ..?